# Clobbered Register armv7 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

i'm using CPULATOR with armv7 assembly and I'm modifying this code to make leds follow a certain pattern using the timer (in this case the pattern is in SEQ),
in the "MODE1" label, i have the register r6 that is previously loaded with the pattern (in the KEY_ISR, , key 0 that should enable this sequence).
Here the problem is, whenever i run the code and press a button, i get the clobbered register (r6) error, even if think i pushed and popped registers correctly, any ideas?

```
.equ SEQ, 0x08040201
.section .vectors, "ax"
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_RESET // reset vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_UND // undefined instruction vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_SVC // software interrrupt vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_ABT_INST // aborted prefetch vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_ABT_DATA // aborted data vector
    .word 0 // unused vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_IRQ // IRQ interrupt vector
    LDR PC, =SERVICE_FIQ // FIQ interrupt vector


.global _start
_start:
    MOV R1, #0b11010010
    MSR CPSR_c, R1 // change to IRQ mode with interrupts disabled
    LDR SP, =0xFFFFFFFC // set IRQ stack to top of A9 on-chip memory
    MOV R1, #0b11010011
    MSR CPSR_c, R1 // change to SVC mode with interrupts disabled
    LDR SP, =0x3FFFFFFC // set SVC stack to top of DDR3 memory
    BL CONFIG_GIC // configure the ARM generic interrupt controller
    BL CONFIG_KEYS // configure the pushbutton KEYs
    BL CONFIG_MPCORE_TIMER // configure the MPCore timer

    /* enable IRQ interrupts in the processor */
    EOR R0,R0
    EOR R1,R1
    EOR R2,R2
    EOR R3,R3
    MOV R1, #0b01010011 // IRQ unmasked, MODE = SVC
    MSR CPSR_c, R1
    EOR R1,R1

loop:
    MVN R0,R0
    B loop


/* Configure the HPS timer to create interrupts at one-second intervals */
CONFIG_MPCORE_TIMER:
    LDR R0, =0xFFFEC600 // MPCORE timer 0 base address
    LDR R3, =200000000 // timeout = 1/(200 MHz) x 200*10^6 = 1 sec
    STR R3, [R0] // write to timer load register
    MOV R3, #7 // set bits: interrupt = 1, mode = 1 (auto), enable = 1
    STR R3, [R0, #0x8] // write to timer control register
    MOV R1, #1
    STR R1, [R0, #0xC] // write 1 in interrupt status 
    // register to clear the interrupt
    BX LR

/* Configure the Generic Interrupt Controller (GIC) */
CONFIG_GIC:
    /* configure the MPCore Timer interrupt */
    LDR R0, =0xFFFED81C // ICDIPTRn: processor targets register 0x1c = [29/4]*4
    LDR R1, =0x00000100 // set target to cpu0 (byte 1 = 29 % 4)
    STR R1, [R0]
    LDR R0, =0xFFFED100 // ICDISERn: set enable register 0=[29/32]*4
    LDR R1, =0x20000000 // set interrupt enable 29=29%32
    STR R1, [R0]
    /* configure the KEYs interrupts */
    LDR R0, =0xFFFED848 // ICDIPTRn: processor targets register
    LDR R1, =0x00000100 // set targets to cpu0
    STR R1, [R0]
    LDR R0, =0xFFFED108 // ICDISERn: set enable register
    LDR R1, =0x00000200 // set interrupt enable
    STR R1, [R0]
    /* configure the GIC CPU interface */
    LDR R0, =0xFFFEC100 // base address of CPU interface
    /* Set Interrupt Priority Mask Register (ICCPMR) */
    LDR R1, =0xFF // enable interrupts of all priorities levels
    STR R1, [R0, #0x04] // ICCPMR
    /* Set the enable bit in the CPU Interface Control Register (ICCICR). This bit allows
    * interrupts to be forwarded to the CPU(s) */
    MOV R1, #1
    STR R1, [R0, #0x00] // ICCICR
    /* Set the enable bit in the Distributor Control Register (ICDDCR). This bit allows
    * the distributor to forward interrupts to the CPU interface(s) */
    LDR R0, =0xFFFED000
    STR R1, [R0, #0x00] // ICDDCR
    BX LR



CONFIG_KEYS:
    // write to the pushbutton port interrupt mask register
    LDR R0, =0xFF200050 // pushbutton key base address
    MOV R1, #0xF // set interrupt mask bits
    STR R1, [R0, #0x8] // interrupt mask register is (base + 8)
    BX LR
    
.global KEY_PRESSED
KEY_PRESSED:
    .word 1 // recent pushbutton KEY pressed


.global SERVICE_IRQ
SERVICE_IRQ:
    PUSH {R0-R7, LR} // save registers
    
    /* get the interrupt ID from the GIC */
    LDR R4, =0xFFFEC100 // GIC CPU interface base address
    LDR R5, [R4, #0x0C] // read the ICCIAR

MPCORE_TIMER_CHECK:
    CMP R5, #29 // check for MPCore timer interrupt
    BNE KEYS_CHECK
    BL MPCORE_TIMER_ISR
    B EXIT_IRQ
KEYS_CHECK:
    CMP R5, #73 // check for KEYs interrupt
UNEXPECTED:
    BNE UNEXPECTED // if not recognized, stop here
    BL KEY_ISR
EXIT_IRQ:
    STR R5, [R4, #0x10] // Write to end-of-interrupt register (ICCEOIR)
    POP {R0-R7, LR}

    SUBS PC, LR, #4

// ---------------------------- ALL OF THE ISR TO A LOOP
.global SERVICE_RESET /* Reset */
SERVICE_RESET:
    B _start
.global SERVICE_UND /* Undefined instructions */
SERVICE_UND:
    B SERVICE_UND
.global SERVICE_SVC /* Software interrupts */
SERVICE_SVC:
    B SERVICE_SVC
.global SERVICE_ABT_DATA /* Aborted data reads */
SERVICE_ABT_DATA:
    B SERVICE_ABT_DATA
.global SERVICE_ABT_INST /* Aborted instruction fetch */
SERVICE_ABT_INST:
    B SERVICE_ABT_INST
.global SERVICE_FIQ /* FIQ */
SERVICE_FIQ:
    B SERVICE_FIQ
    

.extern KEY_PRESSED // externally defined variable
.global KEY_ISR
KEY_ISR:
    LDR R0, =0xFF200050 // base address of KEYs
    LDR R1, [R0, #0xC] // read edge capture register
    STR R1, [R0, #0xC] // clear the interrupt
    LDR R0, =KEY_PRESSED // global variable to return the result
CHECK_KEY0:
    MOVS R3, #0x1
    ANDS R3, R1 // check for KEY0
    BEQ CHECK_KEY1
    LDR R3,=MODE
    LDR R1,[R3]
    MVN R2,R1
    STR R2,[R3]
    LDR R6, =SEQ
    // da qui per compatibilità con il codice originale
    MOVS R2, #0
    STR R2, [R0] // return KEY0 value
    B END_KEY_ISR
CHECK_KEY1:
    MOVS R3, #0x2
    ANDS R3, R1 // check for KEY1
    BEQ CHECK_KEY2
    MOVS R2, #1
    STR R2, [R0] // return KEY1 value
    B END_KEY_ISR
CHECK_KEY2:
    MOVS R3, #0x4
    ANDS R3, R1 // check for KEY2
    BEQ IS_KEY3
    MOVS R2, #2
    STR R2, [R0] // return KEY2 value
    B END_KEY_ISR
IS_KEY3:
    MOVS R2, #3
    STR R2, [R0] // return KEY3 value
END_KEY_ISR:
    BX LR


.global MPCORE_TIMER_ISR
MPCORE_TIMER_ISR:
    LDR R0, =MODE
    LDR R1, [R0]
    LDR R0, =0xFF200000 // base address of led
    CMP R1,#0
    
    BNE MODE1
    LDR R1, [R0]
    CMP R1, #0
    
    MOVEQ R2,#-1
    MOVNE R2,#0
    B FINE

MODE1:

    AND R2, R6, #0xff
    LSR R6, #8
    CMP R6, #0
    LDREQ R6, =SEQ
    MOV R2, #4
    B FINE  
FINE:
    STR R2, [R0]
    LDR R0, =0xFFFEC600 // timer base address
    MOV R1, #1
    STR R1, [R0, #0xC] // write 1 in interrupt status 
    // register to clear the interrupt
    BX LR

.global MODE
MODE:
    .word 0

.end
```

error: At pc=00000200: Function clobbered register(s): r6Details...

Simulator requested a breakpoint.

i tried changing register from r6 to others but the same thing happens, i tried loading the SEQ in other labels but it's always the same error.

Comment: LDR SP, =0x3FFFFFFC  should be 0x40000000 yes, not related to the question but why 0x3FFFFFFC.  stack subtracts first so setting 0x40000000 means 0x3FFFFFFC is the first location used.

Comment: you have to show us a disassembly and what is at 0x200.  provide a complete example please

Comment: so you are setting up and possibly creating interrupts before you setup the processor to handle interrupts?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/W6rXASPVjawY This is the disassembly. I used the logical AND to get only the last two hex characters and light on a single led.

Comment: I setupped the processor to handle the interrupts configuring the gic and the handlers for push buttons and for the timer, what do you mean?

Comment: I think it is not an issue.  The 'problem' is MPCORE_TIMER_ISR routine is clobbering r6.  But you call it from assembler where you don't depend on r6.  The warning is because you have broken an ABI convention, but it doesn't really apply to assembler.  Of course your example is large and difficult to understand without the whole system and a debugger.